# Remove particular row of text in string based on id selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a certain table row in a string. For instance, I have the code below in a string. Lets call the variable that stores the string below `temp`

```
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I have several buttons with id's corresponding to the number of row above. If I click the first button it has a corresponding id of 1, the second button has 2, etc.

What I am getting at is that if I hit these delete buttons, I want to remove the corresponding table row above based on what id (button) I click.

Here is my code so far.

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var temp = $("#detailsBox").val();

   for (i=1; i!=id; i++) {
     if (i=1) {

     }
   }

  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

}
```

How would I delete a part of that string in my variable `temp` based off of the id(button) I click? If I choose button 1, I want to delete the first table row. Button two, second table row, etc. I know I need to replace the string, but how do I remove certain instances within the string?

Comment: That for loop is very unsafe. In the instance that id isn't a number > 1, that loop may never end.

Comment: The id will always be a number greater then 1.

Comment: You could split the string into an array by end of line character (probably `\n\r`) and then use `Array.splice` to remove the appropriate lines from the string. When you are finished use `Array.join` to put them back into a string. If you can't guarantee the rows/cells will always be on new lines, then you might want to convert it into a DOM object, remove it, then save it back to a string.

Comment: Unless another script modifies the `id` attribute. The biggest problem with that loop is the `i != id`. If `id` is undefined, for example, that loop never ends.

Comment: I am getting the id off of a each loop earlier in the script from the index of how many <tr> tags I find fyi.

Comment: It looks to me like you are getting it from an element in the DOM with the class `.delete` that is being clicked.

Comment: You would be right. Beforehand though, I am bringing that id to that particular button through an each loop.

Comment: Why do you have the the rows in a string variable? If you give us more details about what you are trying to achieve, we might provide you a better solution.

Comment: I have the rows in a string variable because its coming from a textarea elements value in a form. The html gets added to this textarea.

Comment: @wowzuzz I updated my answer with jQuery solution. Look at the fiddle I made.

Comment: @wowzuzz ok, that helped. String entered by a user is not safe (a missing `>` or anything). You should use the browser to parse the string and manipulate the resulting DOM - see my answer. It also has the advantage that if you need a different manipulation with the string in the future, you can implement it very easily.

Comment: @thinklinux I'll look at the solution now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML is [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Therefore I suggest you convert your string to DOM and then manipulate on the DOM tree.

Here is a simple solution with jQuery:

```
var row = 1; // the row I want to remove
var temp = $("#myTextarea").value(); // get HTML

var table = $("<tbody>" + temp + "<tbody>"); // creates DOM nodes from HTML
table.find("tr").eq(row - 1).remove();
var tempWithoutRow = table[0].innerHTML;
```

Try yourself in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5dEK/).

Comment: I didn't realize that find would return back an array with a key of 0.

Comment: It actually returns a `jQuery` object which behaves like an array. See description [here](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use jQuery as if that elements are in DOM... and they are not. They are just one string. So you can do something like that:

```
var arr = yourString.split("<tr>");

$(".delete").click(function() {
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
 arr = arr.splice(parceInt(id, 10)-1, 1);
}
```

Now you have array with the right TRs inside. All you have to do is to convert them to string again:

```
var htmlString;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  htmlString += arr[i];
}
```

**UPDATE jQuery WAY**
You can do it with jQuery too. Look at the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/J6HJ2/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the table rows and then filter down to the one you want:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#my-table").find("tr").eq(id + 1).remove();//since your IDs are not zero-indexed and .eq() is
});
```

- Docs for `.eq()`: http://api.jquery.com/eq

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var temp = $("#detailsBox").val();

   for (i=1; i!=id; i++) {
     if (i=1) {

     }
   }

  $(this).parentNode.remove();

}
```

if the .delete is on the td

else if u have `<td><button class="delete"></button></td>`

then it's `$(this).parentNode.parentNode.remove();`

no need for the id if the button is inside the `<tr>`

Answer (score -1):

Easy solution would be to give the rows meaningful ID's and use the following code:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
  $('#row' + $(this).id).remove();
}
```

If you really want to count nameless TR elements in a string you could split them into an array with `split("<tr>")`

Comment: Yeah, that would be a wise idea. The problem is though is there are tons of these table rows already made by a previous developer that don't have an id attribute. That would be very time consuming considering there are lots of table rows without ID's.